# COPY FROM in pgplsql

Tags: postgresql

I try to run the below statement in a pgplsql function and I get an error message "Format '%2f' invalid or incompatible with argument"

```
copy raw_import from 'c:\\files\\test.csv' CSV;
```

If I run directly as a script it works as expected so I've eliminated the contents of test.csv as the problem.  I've also tried wrapping this in an "execute" statement and get the same result.

```
execute 'copy raw_import from ''c:\\files\\test.csv'' CSV';
```

I'm brand new to postgresql so I suspect it's something basic I'm missing - any thoughts would be appreciated.

Requested sample of file - first 3 records:
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l

Table definition:
col1 VARCHAR(100),
col2 VARCHAR(100),
col3 VARCHAR(100),
col4 VARCHAR(100)

Comment: What is in the file, does it have a header line?

Comment: No header line, just data.  Also the same file loads fine if I execute the copy command directly so I don't think it is related to file contents.

Comment: No way to solve this without (a snippet from) the file and the table definition.

Comment: BTW, IIRC the syntay requires a WITH keyword and no quotes around the CSV : `copy the_table ( ... optional column list ...) FROM '/path/to/file.csv' WITH CSV;`

Comment: I'll edit my post with that info but again, I don't think this is related to either because I can import the same table by executing this code outside of a function...

Comment: You did not say it was inside a function. There are some strange things within functions: no DDL, no VACUUM, etc. The path usually refers to the path on the server (and requires super user powers and/or read access) See the fine manual.

Comment: Maybe I'm new and uninformed but I thought "pgplsql" is synonymous with "function".

Comment: There you got me! I dont know exactly, but I think pgplsql is "a superset" of SQL, including , possibly, functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the client and server encodings:

```
cpn=> show server_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

cpn=> show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

If they don't match it could explain why it works when you run it as a script and don't when run at the server, that is, the file is in the wrong encoding.